# Dimension of a complex vector space generated by exponential complex function

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Problem :

Let a complex vector space generated by $E_n = \left\{ e^{2 \pi i k x} \mid -n \leq k \leq n \right\}$. What is $\dim E_n $ ?

My works :

If $\mathrm{span}(E_n)$ is linearly independent then $\dim E_n$ is equal to the number of element inside. Let $U \in \mathrm{span}(E_n)$ then $\exists \lambda_k \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t

$$ U = \sum_{k = -n}^n \lambda_ke^{2 \pi i k x} $$

and I don't know how to show $\lambda_k = 0$ for all $k$. It seems that every element inside are not linearly independent.

Comment: You're a bit confused on the language. You don't say any individual element is linearly independent, you say a set of element is linearly independent. Also, span($E_n$) is way too huge to to be linearly independent; it's the set $E_n$ that's linearly independent. So for example, for $n=1$, $E_1$ is just a set of 3 elements, $\{e^{-2\pi i x}, 1, e^{2\pi i x}\}$.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC, yes I correct this. So I think we should use another approach, e.g the Unit 's reasoning.

Comment: @Jonathan supports MonicaC: I have gotten your explanation regarding my misunderstanding; I have therefore found it unnecessary to keep my answer on and have just taken it down. Unit’s answer deals with it.

Comment: @JackLeGrüß - Thanks for letting me know. That's probably the best move. Plus, I find making a statement and understanding why I was wrong is a great way to learn. Viele Grüße, JonathanZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dim E_n = 2n+1$ because the functions $e^{2\pi i k x}$ are eigenvectors of the derivative map on $E_n$ with distinct eigenvalues $2 \pi i k$.

Comment: If $e^{2\pi i kx}$ is an eigenvector of $f = \mathrm{id}$, and $2\pi i k$ its eigenvalue, then the dimension of its eigenspace is 1. Since each eigenvalue is distinct then the dimension of $E_n$ is equal to the sum of each eigenspace : i.e $2n + 1$. It is correct ?

Comment: Not quite; they're eigenvectors of the *derivative* map $d/dx$. The eigenspaces are each therefore *at least* 1-dimensional. However, the dimension of $E_n$ is *at most* $2n+1$ (because it's the span of that many vectors which are *a priori* not necessarily independent). The sum of the dimensions of the eigenspaces is at most the dimension of $E_n$, and so each eigenspace has dimension exactly 1, and $E_n$ has dimension exactly $2n+1$.

Comment: Understood, Thank you all very much